# Advertising in Answers

Tags: discussion, acceptable-answer

Hi All

I noticed this answer this morning

[What are security issues which are specific to cloud computing?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/341/what-are-security-issues-which-are-specific-to-cloud-computing/1552#1552)

Its a good answer but ends with

'For more info regarding Cloud Computing in India visit - http://www.go4hosting.com'

which is blatant advertising and as far as I can see does not provide any useful information. What should be done in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added a comment for the poster, and removed the link as it is just a marketing page. I agree that the general comment has some valid points, while not really answering the original question, so have left the rest of the comment.

@AviD also sent the poster a strong message re a similar post.

Advertising/Marketing spam is not appropriate on this forum

Oh, and also - thanks for flagging it up Mark!

Comment: Yes, @Mark flagging is absolutely the right response, if a user does this a lot there are some mod-actions that can be taken. In the meantime, if most of the post is a good answer but with some extra advertising (as that one was) - feel free to edit out the crap.